# Add SharePoint Site collection Administrator to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

Is there any way to add a user as Site Collection Administrator in SharePoint Online Sites using Rest API or pnp js?. I am using SPFx react js webpart. I have code in c#, but I cannot use it in my SPFx webpart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the pnpjs library to add the site collection admin.

Firstly, you need to add the below import statement:

```
import { sp, WebEnsureUserResult, UserUpdateResult } from "@pnp/sp";
```

After that, you can use the code as below:

```
sp.web.ensureUser("user.name@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com")
.then((d: WebEnsureUserResult) => {

        var id = d.data.Id;
        console.log(d.data);

        sp.web.getUserById(id).update({
            "IsSiteAdmin":true
        }).then((d:UserUpdateResult) =>{

            console.log(d);
            console.log("Successfully added admin");

        });
    });
```